# add array of unknown length in a dataset javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a js chart and here is a code snipet

```
  var period=array(3,6,7,4,9);
   var marks=array(76,87,45,87,44);
        var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return    Math.round(Math.random()*100)};   

                var lineChartData = {
                    labels : [period[0],period[1],period[2],period[3]],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data :    [marks[0],marks[1],marks[2],marks[3]]
            }
        ]

    }

  window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
  }
```

I need to replace data:[10,20,30...] with an array values[1,3,6,34,56,...] with unknown width. I cant figure out how to inject array inside the 'data'. I tried converting the array to comma separated string and added it like

```
var mar=5+','+6+','+7+','+31;   
data : [mar]
```

and it couldn't work. Every suggestion is welcome
/////////////////////////
I have edited to show marks and period which are arrays of known width. Now I have an array of unknown length that I want to inject to 'data[]'

Comment: where did those numbers `[1,3,6,34,56,...]` come from?

Comment: datasets[0].data = [1, 3, 6, 34, 56 ]

Comment: @Buzinas Thats just an example of an array with those elements

Comment: @jonah yeah, I get that, but I'd like to know where are they coming from in your app. Because I can't see what's exactly your problem.

Comment: @Buzinas I am fetching from database by ajax and returning a string

Comment: @jonah and how is this string formatted? Something like `"1,3,6,34,56"`?

Comment: its a comma separated string variable and i have managed to make it an array using split function

Comment: var marks ="1,3,6,34,56";

Answer (score 1):

You must to make this:

```
 var key = 0;
 var mar = [5,6,7,31];   
 datasets[key].data = mar;
```

This works, but depending the mode you are developing. If you share more code I can help you better

### EDITION

You are making this:

```
    data :    [marks[0],marks[1],marks[2],marks[3]]
```

That's the same to this:

```
    data : marks;
```

The only reason to make the first option is to cut the array in the fourth element, I don't know if you want it. If you don't know how many elements are inside the array, please, use the second option `data:marks;`

Good luck

Comment: Square brackets around `mar` not needed.

Comment: Oh, sorry, a typo mistake. Thank you @MetalMichael for notice me!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have edited the question to add more code. as you can see, I am referencing every array element by index. Supposing I have a longer or shorter array. n i dont want to edit the code

Comment: I edit my answer. There's no changes in my answer because i think it's very simple to write. However, it's possible that I don't understand what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
datasets[0].data = [1, 3, 6, 34, 56];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. But I dont understand where to add your code. Javascript evades me sometimes

Comment: Hey @metalmichael  Please check my edited question. I dont want to call every marks array element. rather paste the whole loop there.